# what percentage of ids in my table have value 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have the following table:

```sql
 users(id INT, timestamp TIMESTAMP, speed DOUBLE PRECISION);

INSERT INTO users(id, timestamp, speed)
VALUES (658,'2016-04-01 00:50:43.673+01',0.93),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:50:45.677+01',0.94),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:50:56.813+01',0.94),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:51:13.332+01', 0),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:51:18.337+01',0),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:51:23.427+01',0),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:51:28.584+01',0),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:51:33.574+01',0),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:51:38.686+01',0),
(658,'2016-04-01 00:51:43.719+01',0)
```

I have over 6000 distinct `id`s. How do I calculate number of `id`s having 50% of rows speed equal to 0?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you two working on the same problem?!?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73866193/number-of-trips-with-similar-characteristics-over-time

Comment: Nico is right -- try something, even if it doesn't work, and I'm confident you will get lots of help in trying to understand where you fell short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query should work:

```
SELECT id FROM users GROUP BY id HAVING SUM(CASE speed WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 2 >= COUNT(speed)
```

- Grouping by user id with `GROUP BY`,
- To count for a special value, I'm using the `case` function to map the value to 1 and the other values to 0 and take the `sum` of the mapped values. Now we have the count of the searched value for each id.
- I use `HAVING` keyword to take only id where the number of searched value is 50% of rows.

Shorter version:

```
SELECT id FROM users GROUP BY id HAVING SUM(CASE speed WHEN 0 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) >= COUNT(speed)
```

Comment: Ah I see. So what's the `* 2`  in `* 2 >= COUNT(speed)` representing?

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance, I am trying to understand where the `50%` is in your answer, so that I understand customizing to say 40%, 60%.. Can you please shade light.

Comment: `SUM(CASE speed WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 2 >= COUNT(speed)` is equivalent to `SUM(CASE speed WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) >= 0.5 * COUNT(speed)`. 0.5 is the percentage.